# Crear círculo transparente con borde de 1 ó 2 px de color

Tags: html, css

Necesito que un `<div>` con `border-radius = 100%` tenga además un borde de 1 o 2 `px` de color blanco. Lo que sucede es que al ponerle un `border: 1px solid white;` a un `<div>` que ya tiene `border-radius:100%;` el borde blanco sale cortado por todos lados. ¿Hay alguna forma de evitar eso?

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con bordes de 1px, 2px y 10px y yo veo bien los bordes, ¿puedes poner un ejemplo?

Comment: Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues una captura de imagen de como quieres lograr que quede el círculo para poder entender mejor y ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código que has intentado hasta ahora? Tiene pinta de que otra propiedad css esté entrando en conflicto con lo que tienes.

Comment: A ver si comprendo bien, ¿quieres que el contenido esté contenido dentro de un círculo pero que el borde se muestre cuadrado?

Comment: Está perfectamente explicado. Quiero un div con border radius del 100% (para que quede circular), pero que ese círculo tenga un borde (border en css) de color blanco. Quedaría como una traba de seguridad de un bote de pintura. Un circulo blanco sin relleno (como en photshop al crear una figura con trazo de 1 pd y sin relleno (para el que sepa de photoshop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edito:
Aunque la capa sea redondeada, la forma donde encaja el contenido sigue siendo rectangular, de manera que podría sobresalir de los bordes y según el caso taparlos y que no se vieran. Para que el contenido no sobresalga se usa el parámetro CSS overflow:hidden;
Nota que no tiene que ver con la solución: Cada radio se asigna a un borde, por lo que para hacer una redonda no son 100% si no 50% ya que el radio se indica desde el centro. Pero el navegador "corta" el radio al 50% así que con radios de mas de 50% se obtiene el mismo resultado.

```css
body {
   background-color:blue;
  }
#redonda {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border: solid 3px white;
    overflow:hidden; /* Evitar que el contenido se visualice fuera del borde*/
  }
```

```html
<div id="redonda"></div>
```

Comment: Eso no es del todo cierto, si pruebas con 100% verás que el resultado es exactamente el mismo. Aún si la buena práctica es 50%, se puede usar 100% sin problema, tal vez con un trabajo mayor por parte del navegador al momento de hacer el render, lo cual pueden ser milisegundos de diferencia.

Comment: Que usar un número mayor al 50% resulte un circulo es pura coincidencia o conveniencia. El radio se calcula del centro, y del centro a la esquina hay un 50%, si fuera un 100% hablaríamos del diámetro.
Que usando un numero mayor en vez de obtener un circulo no obtengamos una figura "parecida" a un rombo redondeado debe ser fruto de una decisión de diseño de restringir el radio al 50%.
¿Usar un 100% resulta un circulo? Ahora si, pero mañana puede que no si en alguna versión futura deciden ser matemáticamente coherentes.

Comment: Asumiendo que tu "coherencia" sea correcta, aún así no estás resolviendo el problema, pues al momento de realizar esta pregunta, el border-radius de 100% genera exactamente el mismo resultado que 50%.

Comment: Que no resuelve el problema, hecho que reconozco probable, lo debe decir el usuario, problema que por cierto has afirmado no ver, así que no entiendo como puedes estas seguro que no lo resuelve. "Puede" que el usuario esté usando un navegador "raro" que no limite el radio al 50% y por eso tenga resultados inesperados.

Comment: Gracias! Es simple y conciso. Justo lo que yo necesitaba.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví No es coincidencia que un `border-radius` mayor que 50% (hablando de un cuadrado porque en un rectángulo puede haber esquinas de más de 50%) dé como resultado un círculo, la especificación de `border-radius` lo contempla para que no se solapen las curvas: "_Corner curves must not overlap: When the sum of any two adjacent border radii exceeds the size of the border box, UAs must proportionally reduce the used values of all border radii until none of them overlap._ "

Comment: Esa es otra manera de decir lo mismo, que se limite el radio para no solaparse es una decisión de diseño, y "podría" no estar implementado en algunos navegadores, por eso es mejor usar valores exactos y no dar por supuesto que un valor fuera de rango será truncado.
Cuando digo "coincidencia" me refiero a usar valores fuera de rango y que funcionen sin saber porqué.

Comment: Por otra parte, para ser sincero, viendo que se ha arreglado el problema, creo mas probable que se solucionara por el overflow:hidden; que por el tamaño de radio. A ver si @CristianAnnese nos saca de dudas.

Comment: No entiendo tu punto de vista, la especificación es clara al respecto, dice lo que el navegador debe hacer en ese caso concreto, no lo deja al criterio del navegador como puede ocurrir en otros casos. Además si no funcionara así las esquinas redondeadas se romperían continuamente en elementos que cambian de tamaño y eso no ocurre. Tu mismo dices que seguramente el problema lo haya solucionado el overflow.

Comment: El OP no ha puesto un código de ejemplo reproduciendo el error por lo que sólo podemos hacer conjeturas, sin embargo el comportamiento de los navegadores que soportan la propiedad con `border-radius:100%` es correcto -hasta donde yo sé- en todos los casos

Comment: Muchachos, tratemos de comprendernos y ayudarnos a aprender mutuamente, para así todos crecer. El problema, para ser sincero, lo solucioné de la manera menos práctica: haciendo una imagen en Photoshop y colocándola de fondo del div. Sin embargo, la respuesta de Arnau me resultó lógica, con criterio, con seguridad, y diferente a lo que yo venía haciendo (y que no funcionaba). Por lo tanto, ese fue mi motivo para darla como correcta. Ninguna respuesta o criterio es mejor que el otro; solo son diferentes y apuntan a lo mismo. Gracias a ambos por el interés y por compartir su conocimiento conmigo.

Comment: Pues eso no está bien, si el código no soluciona el problema y das la respuesta como válida otra persona en la misma situación llegará aquí y no le servirá la respuesta. Stackoverflow es un repositorio de conocimiento o de resolución de dudas, o como se quiera llamar, no sólo sirve para ayudar a una persona concreta sino en un futuro a todos los que puedan tener el mismo problema.

Comment: No creo que haya mal rollo ni nada, yo solo expreso mi opinión y Arnau la suya (y cualquier otro que participe la suya propia también), aquí queda el punto de vista de cada uno en la discusión para que otros juzguen y valoren según su criterio

Comment: Los navegadores no discriminan entre usuario y usuario. Si a mi me funcionaría, por qué a otro no? Ya está, hay que dejarla ahí. Para qué discugir a ver quién tiene la razón?